# Why React Link is updating the URL not the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={LocationSelection} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/category/:categoryid" component={Category} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```

Here,the `category` component I want to render. Inside `category` component I've a `Footer` component`& inside that, I've a`Dishes` component I'm mapping.

```
      <div className="flex flex-row  items-center hide-scroll gap-4 px-md mt-3 whitespace-nowrap overflow-x-scroll overflow-y-hidden">
        {categoryList
          .filter((item) => item.category_id !== currentId)
          .map((category) => {o
            return (
              <Dishes
                key={category.category_id}
                category={category}
                languageLabels={languageLabels}
                loading={loadingCategories}
                isInFooter={true}
              />
            );
          })}
      </div>
```

Dishes.js

```
<Link
          className={`${
            isInFooter
              ? "relative rounded aspect-w-7 aspect-h-3 break-words bg-gray-200 min-w-md"
              : "relative rounded aspect-w-16 aspect-h-17 bg-gray-200 w-full"
          }`}
          to={`/category/${category.category_id}`}
          onClick={getCurrentId}
        >
          <img
            src={category.image_url}
            alt=""
            className="object-cover w-full h-full rounded absolute inset-0"
          />
          <div className="absolute left-2.5 top-1.25 right-1.25 ">
            <h3 className="font-metropolis_bold uppercase text-white whitespace-normal">
              {category.title}
            </h3>
            <p className="text-xxs font-metropolis_medium text-white">
              {category.options} {languageLabels.options_available}
            </p>
          </div>
        </Link>
```

This updates the URL but not entire page.
I've tried wrapping this component with `withRouter` but still page in not updating.

Comment: "This updates the URL but not entire page" does this means that your component is not rendered, but URL in browser is changed?

Comment: exactly, That's right @Nemanja

Answer (score 0):

Remove `exact` from `path=/` and add it for `/category` path like this

```
<Switch>
         <Route path="/category/:categoryid" exact component={Category} /> 
          <Route path="/" component={LocationSelection} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
         
        </Switch>
```

Comment: Really sorry for late replay, and I tried your solution but it's not letting me go to another page. It's a big application I didn't show you all the code.
```
          <Route path="/" exact component={LocationSelection} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/verification" component={OTPVerification} />
          <Route path="/home" component={Homepage} />
          <Route path="/loyalyty" component={LoyaltyPage} />
          <Route path="/category/:categoryid" component={Category} />
```

Comment: If I here remove the `exact` from `path=/` It's not letting me go to `/home`. It's bit confusing to explain everything here. Sorry once again for keeping you wait. @Nemanja